# Put together complex object with nested collections

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

Tables keep information about loading of data. Its loading is something I renamed to batch (which might not be a perfect name). Steps and Sets are meta-tables, already defined and their content will probably not be updated in the future (at least nothing old will get deleted). Sets are definitions of types of data, like "a csv file wtih this or that". Several sets make a step. Several steps make a batch. It is possible for a set to be tied to multiple steps, so the set can be reused. Actual (loaded) data is stored in other tables, but it is not important for this particular task.

I have this (simplified) DB structure:
[image]

(Logs table does not have foreign key constraints.)

from which I need to obtain something like this:

```
public class JoinedModel
{
    public Batch Batch { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Step> Steps { get; set; }
}

public class Step
{
    public int StepId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Set> Sets { get; set; }
}

public class Set
{
    public int SetId { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string EventCode { get; set; }
}
```

How to join a single `Batch` with a collection of `Step` objects, each having a collection of appropriate `Set` objects (notice that output set class has event code, obtained from `Logs` and `Events` tables)?

Tried multiple 'from', joins, grouping, but I am not that good to work out the solution. Is it possible to make something like this from one statement, or do I have to select `Batch` separately and then take the rest? How then?

DB design cannot be changed.

Comment: "Tried multiple 'from....." I don't see any kind of attempt. Do you want an EF solution? Pure SQL? LinQ to SQL?

Comment: As in the tag (thought it is enough), a LINQ to SQL. Attempts were made, a ton, but really, nothing worked as intended and I don't know which might be "helpful" and representative to add to the question.

Comment: I'm not sure your model makes logical sense. You say several sets make a step - but in your model, several steps also make a set (and the many-to-many relationships are recorded via the mapping table)! There is also a one-to-one relation between logs and steps, and also between logs and sets, which means no step with multiple sets, or no set with multiple steps, can be entered into the log table. I think you may need to go back to the drawing board - or be a bit more specific about what you're trying to achieve, so that we can advise on the design.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Logs> logs = new List<Logs>();
            List<Step> steps = new List<Step>();
            List<Set> sets = new List<Set>();
            List<Batch> batches = new List<Batch>();
            List<Event> events = new List<Event>(); 


            int BatchId = 123;

            var results = (from log in logs
                           join step in steps on log.Steps_StepId equals step.StepId
                           join set in sets on log.Sets_SetId equals set.SetId
                           join batch in batches on log.Batch_BatchId equals batch.BatchId
                           join _event in events on log.Events_EventId equals _event.EventId
                           select new { log = log, step = step, set = set, batch = batch, _event = _event })
                           .Where(x => x.batch.BatchId == BatchId)
                           .Select(x => new {
                               description = x.batch.Description,
                               eventCode = x._event.Code,
                               date = x.log.Date,
                               stepId = x.step.StepId,
                               stepDescription = x.step.Description,
                               setType = x.set.SetId
                           }).ToList();


        }

    }
    public class Logs
    {
        public int Batch_BatchId { get; set; }
        public int Steps_StepId { get; set; }
        public int Sets_SetId { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Events_EventId { get; set; }

    }
    public class JoinedModel
    {
        public Batch batch { get; set; }
        public List<Step> Steps { get; set; }
    }

    public class Step
    {
        public int StepId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<Set> Sets { get; set; }
    }

    public class Set
    {
        public int SetId { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string EventCode { get; set; }
    }
    public class Batch
    {
        public int BatchId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
    public class Event
    {
        public int EventId { get; set; }
        public int Code { get; set; }
    }
}
```